# error: Multiple commands produce '/Civilsdaily-gjggvnysmawfxocznghsnymtulyq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Civilsdaily.app/SimpleLineIcons.ttf':

Tags: ios, react-native, fonts

Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace Civilsdaily.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Civilsdaily -destination id=AE1E65F9-A867-4C6A-8ADA-0604A97ADE7B

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Using build description from disk
Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/mdamil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Civilsdaily-gjggvnysmawfxocznghsnymtulyq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Civilsdaily.app/Zocial.ttf':

1. Target 'Civilsdaily' (project 'Civilsdaily') has copy command from '/Users/mdamil/project/phone/Civilsdaily/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Zocial.ttf' to '/Users/mdamil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Civilsdaily-gjggvnysmawfxocznghsnymtulyq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Civilsdaily.app/Zocial.ttf'
2. That command depends on command in Target 'Civilsdaily' (project 'Civilsdaily'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/mdamil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Civilsdaily-gjggvnysmawfxocznghsnymtulyq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Civilsdaily.app/SimpleLineIcons.ttf':

1. Target 'Civilsdaily' (project 'Civilsdaily') has copy command from '/Users/mdamil/project/phone/Civilsdaily/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/SimpleLineIcons.ttf' to '/Users/mdamil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Civilsdaily-gjggvnysmawfxocznghsnymtulyq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Civilsdaily.app/SimpleLineIcons.ttf'
2. That command depends on command in Target 'Civilsdaily' (project 'Civilsdaily'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/mdamil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Civilsdaily-gjggvnysmawfxocznghsnymtulyq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Civilsdaily.app/Octicons.ttf':

1. Target 'Civilsdaily' (project 'Civilsdaily') has copy command from '/Users/mdamil/project/phone/Civilsdaily/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Octicons.ttf' to '/Users/mdamil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Civilsdaily-gjggvnysmawfxocznghsnymtulyq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Civilsdaily.app/Octicons.ttf'
2. That command depends on command in Target 'Civilsdaily' (project 'Civilsdaily'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, react-native-vector-icons and native-base both bundle the same font files. (And for some reason we also have one of them bundled ourselves; I'll be sure to remove that one.) Before updating to Xcode 10 / Mojave, there was no issue. The only change was to update from Xcode 9 to Xcode 10.